# visualstudio create new state for the agile process

Tags: azure-devops, state, agile

[Disabled button screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fCTUp.jpg)

I am part of the Project Collection Administrators group, but button to create new state is disabled for me. How can I add new state.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Agile process is one of the System processes, And it is locked from being changed. If you want to add a customized state, you need to create a inherited process from Agile process first.

> System processes —Agile, Basic, Scrum, and CMMI—which are locked from being changed.

> Inherited processes, which you can customize and that inherit definitions from the system process from which they were created. System processes are owned and updated periodically by Microsoft. Any updates made to a system process automatically cause an update to your inherited process.

See [document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/organizations/settings/work/inheritance-process-model?toc=%2Fazure%2Fdevops%2Freference%2Ftoc.json&bc=%2Fazure%2Fdevops%2Freference%2Fbreadcrumb%2Ftoc.json&view=azure-devops&tabs=agile-process#system-versus-inherited-processes) here for more information.

See below steps to create an Inherited process:

1,Go to **organization settings**-->**Process** under **Boards**-->Click the 3dots-->**Create inherited process**

[image]

2, Now you can create new state in the inherited process.
[image]

3, Change your project's process to the inherited process created above. So that the new state can show up in the project.

Go to **organization settings**-->**Process** under **Boards**-->go the **Team projects** tab

[image]

Click the **3dots** beside your project-->Click Change process to change your project's process to above inherited process
[image]

Comment: Thank you very much. I Waa reading documentation, but could not figure out. Your answer was very descriptive!